# Merge not pulling through second dataframe's values for extra column

Tags: python, pandas, merge

So I have this code which works but doesn't pull in the "Eur Equivalent" values. I've checked dtypes and they're float64 so it should work.

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df3, fx_ytd[["Period", "CCY", "EUR EQUIVALENT"]], on=["Period", "CCY"], how="left")
```

The result is that you get all these columns just the Eur Equivalent column is not populated with any numbers despite, `fx_ytd` dataframe being complete.

fx_ytd

| Period | CCY | EUR EQUIVALENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12 | EUR | 1 |
| 2022-12 | GBP | 0.867 |

df3

| Name | Amt | Period | CCY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxy | 5067 | 2022-12 | EUR |
| xxya | 564893 | 2022-12 | GBP |

merged_df :

| Name | Amt | Period | CCY | EUR EQUIVALENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxy | 5067 | 2022-12 | EUR |  |
| xxya | 564893 | 2022-12 | GBP |  |

INSTEAD OF:

| Name | Amt | Period | CCY | EUR EQUIVALENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxy | 5067 | 2022-12 | EUR | 1 |
| xxya | 564893 | 2022-12 | GBP | 0.867 |

Comment: `"EUR EQUIVALENT"` is not as `Eur Equivalent`

Comment: Check that the dtypes for "Period", "CCY" are the same in both dataframes

Comment: They are both the same dtypes in both dataframes "Period" & "CCY" are both objects

Comment: I'm not able to replicate: https://onecompiler.com/python/3zj862y5z  Perhaps there are some stray whitespace characters in your data that are messing up the merge?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, I was using pandas version 0.19.2 and needed to write the dataframes(fx_ytd & df3) to excel and then open them again e.g.:
 `df7 =  pd.read_excel(r"path") etc`

Then the merge worked.